# How to set custom value to Wix Bundle Log Element?

Tags: variables, logging, path, wix, bootstrapper

If I put a hard-coded value it works fine

```
<Log PathVariable="C:\myProjectDir\myLogs\log.txt"/>
```

But if I make a separate variable and replace the hard-code, it does NOT work

```
<Log PathVariable="[LogLocation]"/>
<Variable Name="LogLocation" bal:Overridable="no" Type="string" Value="C:\myProjectDir\myLogs\log.txt" Persisted="yes"/>
```

I found something on the lines of `<WixVariable Id="WixBundleLog"/>` but I don't really know how to use it.

**My end goal here is that I have a bootstrapper application and I want to change the location where logs of my msi and exe installation is created**

I able able to change a **Variable** element value using `_bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["LogLocation"] = "C:\ProjectGorilla\logs\log.txt"`

Using the above code in C#, the ***Variable Id="LogLocation"*** is changed but that change is not reflected in ***Log element's PathVariable***

**So, my question is how can I put a variable in PathVariable attribute of Log element**

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/log.html), the `PathVariable` attribute is:

> Name of a Variable that will hold the path to the log file. An empty value will cause the variable to not be set. The default is "WixBundleLog".

`PathVariable` does not specify the path where the (bundle) log will be written. It is a variable that the BA is supposed to read if it wants to copy the file somewhere else. The Burn engine never reads this variable's value so changing it during runtime won't do anything.

The (bundle) log is created (https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/58abd6993afba08b39e37b0e76b1790161df9231/src/burn/engine/engine.cpp#L499) before loading the BootstrapperApplication (https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/58abd6993afba08b39e37b0e76b1790161df9231/src/burn/engine/engine.cpp#L545). There is no way for the BA to change the path.

The package (MSI, EXE, etc) log locations work the same way today as the bundle log. However since they are created after loading the BA, it's theoretically possible that someone could implement a feature so that the BA can change their path.

Comment: At the end you said, MSI log location change should be theoretically possible. Any idea on how should I go about looking for that theoritically possible answer ?

Comment: @Lelouch Create a feature request for allowing the BA to change the path of package logs at https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues. And then either implement it yourself or hope someone else implements it. Once you get a build of the toolset with that new feature, then your BA could use that new functionality.